# redshift first_value vs min value

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Trying to understand what is better in performance when using window functions in Redshift

```
min(Case when colc='y' then val else Null end) 
Over(partition by cola,order by colb rows BETWEEN CURRENT ROW and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

OR

```
first_value(Case when colc='y' then val else Null end) 
Over(partition by cola order by colb rows BETWEEN CURRENT ROW and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Logically `first_value` should be quicker but just want to confirm if anyone has done a POC.

Comment: first of all, why should they produce equal output? you order by `colb` but evaluate `val` column, so `first_value` output can be different from `min`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done a POC and see no need to do one.  The two constructs produce essentially the same execution plan, with just some minor logical differences at the lowest level.  You are correct that `first_value()` can "short-circuit" the execution by retrieving the first encountered value for each row, rather than "remembering" the minimum and doing one additional comparison (only the value from the current row needs to be compared to the minimum of the previous row).

How important is the comparison?  Well, think about what drives performance.  The data in all the referenced columns needs to be read.  The columns from the `partition by` need to be sorted or hashed.  The columns from the `order by` then need to be sorted.  After all that work, one additional comparison per row is a negligible difference.

I don't want to say that it is nothing -- you might find something, say a 1% difference.  However, that additional work is really nothing compared to everything else the construct does.